# Why do I see 403 forbidden in Azure application gateway?

Tags: azure, http-error, azure-application-gateway

The error I see when accessing https://www.example.com regardless of whether I have a listener (443) and rule is:

```
403 - Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

If I add a listener on port 443, attach a valid certificate and rule, I get the same error message. If I dig www.example.com, I can see it's resolving to the public IP of the application gateway.

http://www.example.com works as expected with a listener on port 80 and rules directing traffic to backend virtual machines hosting Apache.

I should add that this has been set using the Azure Portal. Should I be using PowerShell? Some forums suggest the portal is flaky.

Comment: Do you have WAF enabled ? Did you check firewall logs for any request getting blocked?

Comment: WAF isn't enabled. Where can I find the firewall logs? On the backend, I can see the request is not hitting the web server backend.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics#diagnostic-logging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was resolved and ties in with a redirection problem we were experiencing.

The problem appears to be a combination of the following:

- We had a listener on port 443 without a hostname.
- It appears the order of path-based rules is important when there's a listener without a hostname.

As a rule of thumb, path-based rules should be below basic rules. Also, if the app gateway is used for multiple sites, ensure hostnames are defined for listeners.

Answer (score 1):

My Application Gateway is configured with a `multisite` listener. For me, I had selected `Enable SSL Profile` on the listener. I am not using path-based rules and WAF is turned off.

Although I had configured an SSL profile, I guess there is an error in the certificate. It is (currently) under preview, but I don't think I fully understand what it's supposed to do - needs more reading.

Instead of using SSL Profile on the listener, I was able to use `Use well known CA certificate` option under `HTTP settings`. This resolved the `403` error.